# Xcode 8 quitting when syncing changes to Xamarin 6.1

Tags: xcode, xamarin, interface-builder

My app is Xib-based and I've been relying on Xcode to manage/setup all my xibs thus far. I just updated to Xcode 8 and Xamarin Studio 6.1 and now every time I switch back to Xamarin from Xcode, Xcode silently quits. No error. Just gone.

As soon as I bring Xamarin's window into focus, I see the status showing "syncing changes" as it normally does. The changes do get saved but then Xcode just disappears and I have to reopen everything again.

Anyone else experiencing this? Have a fix/workaround?

UPDATE:
I just updated Xamarin Studio to 6.1.1 and this is still happening :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This change in behavior happens because Xcode 8 ignores some AppleScript commands that Xamarin Studio has long relied on to refresh projects in Xcode 7.3 and earlier.  When Xamarin Studio notices that Xcode has ignored those commands, it falls back to closing Xcode completely instead.  That fallback code path has been removed for Xamarin Studio 6.2, so Xamarin Studio 6.2 will no longer forcibly close Xcode 8 during the synchronization. You can keep an eye on the [Xamarin Release Blog](https://releases.xamarin.com/) for notifications about the first Alpha and Beta versions of Xamarin Studio 6.2 over the next month or so.

Comment: i eagerly await 6.2's release. I personally would vote for a 6.1.2 patch with this fix included.